# MYSQL, PHP, Как запрограммировать структуру данных для полного файлового пути. Какая структура таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql, структуры, таблицы

Не подскажете, как запрограммировать в SQL вот такую структуру данных: полный путь до некоторого файла?
Необходимо, чтобы была также возможность быстрого поиска по нескольким, но не всем составляющим этого пути.

Например:

Если 111/222/333/4444/55 это полный путь к некоторому файлу, то если на входе 111 то все полные пути содержащие 111 должны быть выведены.

Если на входе 222 55, то все полные пути содержащие 222 и 55 должны быть выведены.

Если на входе 333, то та же самая петрушка.

Но и такой вариант запроса должен сработать: 4444 и 111
И такой тоже: 111 и 55 и 222

То есть в запросе все равно в каком порядке будут директории/каталоги/фильтры указаны.

Мне вот привиделась реализация вида:

```
Знач : Перв : Втор : Тр : Чет : Пят

file :111:222:333:4444:55
```

Но что-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: С:\файлы\большие\Средние\Малые и поиск в базе name LIKE '%Средние%

Comment: Спасибо. А насколько like медленный? И что если мне поступает запрос "55 222"